# Modify $READLINE_LINE and $READLINE_POINT values inside bash script

Tags: bash, autocomplete

When answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076611/bash-expand-cd-with-shortcuts-like-zsh/25096279#25096279) I used a very messy `bind` function to modify the current line according to the result of my `automplete.sh` script.

As I ended up using this script for my personal use, I tried to simplify the `bind` and try to do all the reading and modification directly inside the script.

So far, I can access `$READLINE_LINE` and `$READLINE_POINT` and extract the informations I need, but I can't replace the current value. Quotting `bind` mand page, this should work though :

> When shell-command is executed, the shell sets the READLINE_LINE variable to the contents of the readline line buffer and the READLINE_POINT variable to the current location of the insertion point. If the executed command changes the value of READLINE_LINE or READLINE_POINT, those new values will be reflected in the editing state

I bound my scipt with `bind -x '"\t":autocomplete.sh'`, and did something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
#autocomplete.sh
BASE="${READLINE_LINE% *} "
LAST_CMD="${READLINE_LINE##* }"
EXPANSION=($(magical_autocomplete $LAST_CMD))
#we store the desired value for the line in ${EXPANSION[0]}
[[ ${#EXPANSION[@]} -gt 1 ]] && echo ${EXPANSION[@]:1} #we echo the match if there are more than 1

#Doesn't work, even with simple values like READLINE_LINE="test" or READLINE_POINT=0
READLINE_LINE=${EXPANSION[0]}
READLINE_POINT=${#READLINE_LINE}
#echo READLINE_LINE READLINE_POINT echoes the correct value here
```

After execution of the script, the correct matches are displayed, but the current line feed is not updated. As I am echo-ing some informations, I can't just redirect the ouptut of my script in the `bind` part. Why can I read from the variables but not write into it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just by the same reason why this won’t work:

```
$ export a=1
$ bash -c 'echo $a; let a++'
1
$ echo $a
1
```

Environment variables are *heritable*, not shareable. Since `autocomplete.sh` is executed as a new child process, it can read all parent’s variables, but can‘t push new values back.

To modify `READLINE_LINE` and `READLINE_POINT` you have to execute your autocomplete in the same process – `source` and functions will help you.

```
# autocomplete.sh
# should be sourced from ~/.bashrc or something

autocomplete() {
    echo $READLINE_LINE $READLINE_POINT
    EXPANSION=($(magical_autocomplete $READLINE_LINE))
    #we store the desired value for the line in ${EXPANSION[0]}
    [[ ${#EXPANSION[@]} -gt 1 ]] && echo ${EXPANSION[@]:1}

    READLINE_LINE=${EXPANSION[0]}
    READLINE_POINT=${#READLINE_LINE}
}
```

Binding:

```
if [[ -s "$HOME/.bashrc.d/autocomplete.sh" ]]; then
    source "$HOME/.bashrc.d/autocomplete.sh" 
    bind -x '"\t" : autocomplete'
fi
```